# MySql select with max getting wrong ID?

Tags: mysql

When I run my select

`SELECT id, MAX(amount) AS value FROM bids`

It seems to return the wrong id... it returns the first id value rather then the MAX(amount) selected id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's expected - you're using an aggregate function without any 'group by' clause. MySQL is being polite and assuming you want a GLOBAL max on the table, whereas you most likely wanted to do this:

```
SELECT id, MAX(amount) AS value
FROM bids
GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to do something like this (though I'm not sure it's the best way to get the data you want):

```
SELECT id
FROM bids
WHERE amount = MAX(amount)
```

You could perhaps add a `LIMIT` or an `ORDER BY` clause (or both) to further pare down the data you're looking for.

You could also try:

```
SELECT id
FROM bids
ORDER BY amount DESC
LIMIT 1
```

to get a single `id` for the max `amount` in your table.  And if you did it this way, you'd eventually want to put an index on your `amount` field to speed up the query.  This is all assuming you want the `id` that goes along with the highest `amount` in your table and that's it.